# BitBucket + AppHarbor not triggering

Tags: appharbor

I am trying to configure the auto deploy between the 2.
So I went to the option in AppHarbor, and it started the little wizard, and I picked the proper repo and clicked Add, it then took me to Bitbucket and I authorized it.

Well I expected that it would trigger, but apparently it is not triggering.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: We may be having some temporary issues, we're look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I think the system is inserting the wrong token, when I manually added the token it started working.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment we are not triggering a build when you create the bridge, you have to push to your bitbucket repository once the bridge is created. This is something we are working on, and will be changed at some point.